# Is "in which" correct here?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

> 1. We give an overview to knowledge representation.
> 2. Our proposed strategy is based on knowledge representation

What is the best way to combine these two sentences?

For example, is it correct if I write it as:

> We give an overview to knowledge representation ***in which*** our proposed
>   strategy is relied on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to combine the two statements into a single sentence is...

> We give an overview **of** knowledge representation, **on which** our proposed strategy is based.

Note that in this construction, the "referent" of *which* is *knowledge representation*.

Answer (score 1):

It would feel more natural to me to say something like this:

> We **will** give an overview **of** knowledge representation, in which **we will present** our proposed strategy.

Comment: Not necessarily; it's common in abstracts to use the present tense rather than the future.

Comment: This rephrasing significantly changes the meaning, in that it no longer contains the assertion of OP's second statement (that *our proposed strategy **is based on** knowledge representation*).